# Trouble with Select statement

Tags: sql

I  have a following  select  query That runs well

```
SELECT
  division, 
  division_name, 
  object_account, 
  account_description, 
  Sum(value) AS PreferedSpend 
FROM jde_dw.blanket_rpt 
WHERE division = 02 
AND vendor_type = 'PV' 
AND month = 07 
AND year = 2013 
GROUP BY division, division_name, object_account, account_description 
ORDER BY division
```

Now I want to add a column that shows total spend it would be the same query as above but without the vendor_type condition in the where statement.

So the final query will show  Division, division_name, Object_account, Account_Description, Value( as preferred ) and value as( total which includes everything)

How can I do this?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking here

Comment: I think you're looking for [Concatenation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx)

Comment: This needs a lot more description: "total which includes everything." Perhaps you can show us some example data and result?

Comment: Please show sample table with data.  What database is this for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the condition inside the `SUM()` so that only matching rows contribute to the sum:

```
SELECT
  division, 
  division_name, 
  object_account, 
  account_description, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN vendor_type = 'PV' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as PreferedSpend,
  SUM(value) AS TotalSpend
FROM jde_dw.blanket_rpt 
WHERE division = 02 
AND month = 07 
AND year = 2013 
GROUP BY division, division_name, object_account, account_description 
ORDER BY division
```